# Entity Framework Core error on updating an existing record

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

In my `ASP.NET-Core Code First project`, I'm getting the following error on `SaveChangesAsync()` in the following `Action Method`:

**Error**

```
DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded
```

**Action Method**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateWeekDay(int iWeekDay)
{
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
            WeekModel oWeekModel = new WeekModel();
            oWeekModel.DayOfWeek= iWeekDay;
            _context.Update(oWeekModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View();
        }
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class WeekModel
{
    [Key]
    public int WeekId { get; set; }
    public int DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

**NOTE**: The corresponding table `Weeks` in the SQL Server 2014 Db has `WeekId as an identity column and as the PK`. Moreover, the table contains only one record.

**UPDATE**:

Following this [Post from user sstan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988176/1232087), I tried the following  in the above Action Method. It does not give me an error but does not update the db as well:

```
WeekModel oWeekModel = new WeekModel();
_context.WeekModel.Attach(oWeekModel);
oWeekModel.DayOfWeek= iWeekDay;
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Why do you create new entity for update?

Comment: You'd need to attach the newly created model before passing it to update method. Or do a query to fetch it first, otherwise it's not tracked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice from `@Tseng` and `@ademcaglin` and [this post from `@sstan`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30988176/1232087) I was able to resolve the issue as follows. **NOTE**: Credit goes to above mentioned users (my thanks to these users):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateWeekDay(int iWeekDay)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      WeekModel oWeekModel = _context.WeekModel.Where(s => s.DayOfWeek > 0).FirstOrDefault<CurrentYear>();
      _context.WeekModel.Attach(oWeekModel);
      oWeekModel.DayOfWeek= iWeekDay;
      await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
      return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to attach fetched entity. You can remove `_context.WeekModel.Attach(oWeekModel)`.

Comment: @ademcaglin Per your suggestion, I removed the attach fetched entity and it still works. Could you please explain why attach fetched entity was not necessary here and when it will be necessary?

Comment: You don't need because you didn't create new entity, you fetched it from database via `DbContext`. Example in your question need to attach(as @Tseng said) because you created new entity(not fetched). Also see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx