# Why use Attach for update Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

While searching for the best practivies of performing CRUD operation via EF I noticed that it is highly recommended to use `Attach()` or `Find()` methods before updating an entity. It works well and according to EF documentation these methods fetch the entity to context that is quite clear for me. But the followind code confused me pretty much

```
public void Update(object entity)
{
    Record record = new Record() {
        id = 1,
        value = 5
    };
    using (SomeContext ctx = new SomeContext())
    {
        ctx.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Assume we have a record with id = 1 in database. On this condition the code above will update the record (set the value to 5). The question is why it works? And then why should I use `Attach()`?. As far as I understand the record wasn't attached to context in any way. I read relevant chapters of [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969) book and [the tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/update-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx) but they use 2-query-approach. Also I surfed SO but didn't find answer on my question. Help me with explanation or some good matherials, please.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but which is not currently being tracked by the context - which is true in your case - then you can tell the context to track the entity using the `Attach` method on `DbSet`. 
So in summary  what `Attach` method does is track the entity in the context and change its state  to **`Unchanged`**. When you modify a property after that, the tracking changes will change its state to **`Modified`** for you.
In the case you expose above you are telling explicitly that state is **`Modified`** but also to attach the entity to your context. You can find a detailed explanation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987806/dbset-attachentity-vs-dbcontext-entryentity-state-entitystate-modified).

**When should you use `Attach` method?**

When you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but want to make some changes:

```
var entity= new Entity{id=1};
context.YourDbSet.Attach(entity); 

// Do some change...  
entity.value=5;

context.SaveChanges();
```

This is the same:

```
 context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged; 

// Do some change... 
entity.value=5; 

context.SaveChanges();
```

**When should you change entity's State to Modified explicitly?**

When you have an entity that you know already exists in the database but the changes have already been made then. The same scenario of your example

Comment: thank you, but why this record is currently tracked by the context?

Comment: If the entity is currently tracked and you change some property, the entity's state should change to `Modified` due to the tracking change, but for that your entities should meet this [requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I read the chapter before and maybe really misunderstood something but the question is still here. If I follow the requirements do all entities are tracked autmatically? My example shows that newly added object is already someway tracked by the context, so why should I use `Attach()`? And why that new object is tracked? Thank you for explaining, maybe I dig too deep.

Comment: @VitaliiIsaenko Why that new object is tracked? Because when you call `ctx.Entry(record)` the DbContext will automatically Find or Create your entity and Attach it to the context.

Comment: Exactly, you don't need to use `Attach` method in that scenario.

Comment: For saving a list of class objects, then can we do it without attaching.